# Simulation of rolling 2 dice for snake eyes and calculation of average in JAVA

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, simulation

So I have to write a simulation of two dice rolling 1000 times with a for loop, and calculating the average of a snake eyes happening.
So far I got:

```
public class RollDiceforloop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int die1, die2, snakeye, rolls;
        snakeye = 0;

        die1 = 0;
        die2 = 0;

        for (rolls = 0; rolls < 1000; rolls++) {
            die1 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            die2 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            if (die1 != 1 && die2 != 1); {

            }
            if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 1) {
                snakeye +=1;
            }
        }
        TextIO.putln(""+snakeye+" snake eyes over "+rolls+" rolls of the dice.");
    }
}
```

I did not calculate the average yet as I want to make sure that I am doing it right. I get very low numbers of snake eyes... Is my for loop correct?

Comment: What kind of low numbers did you get, and what would you expect ?

Comment: do you get around 30?

Comment: I get things like 19, 23... 27... Just wanted to make sure it's correct.

Comment: @ChrisVieulles it sounds correct to me

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! I felt it was very low and I might have messed up something. 
I am trying to add the average now, but when I add:

 float average = snakeye / rolls;

I always get 0.0 ... I am not sure why, since my numbers are correct.

Comment: Odds are 1/36, so the expectation is about 27.7.

Comment: If you take float average =  snakeye / rolls the jvm will do (int) snakeyes / (int) rolls -> (int) 0. float average = (float) 0. This means that it does the converstion to float after division. If you want to perserve all decimals you have to explicitly cast to float before divding by typing (float) before snakeye.

Comment: I changed it for:  
float average = snakeye / 1000f;   
and now I get 0.019 for 19 snake eyes, 0.021 for 21 snake eyes obviously, etc. I think I got it right!
Thanks

Comment: Okay so I realized I messed up, and what I am asked is not to get the average over rolling the dice 1000 times, but instead, I have to play 1000 times and find the average time it takes to get to snake eyes...

Answer (score 0):

i think your loop is working very well and make a random number for the two dice 1000 time 
and you calculate the number of time in strange way (it will work but not Effective) better to do it like this and i calculate the average too

```
public class RollDiceforloop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int die1, die2, snakeye, rolls;
        snakeye = 0;

        die1 = 0;
        die2 = 0;

        for (rolls = 0; rolls < 1000; rolls++) {
            die1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            die2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            if (die1 == 1 && die2 == 1) {
                snakeye += 1;
            }
        }
        TextIO.putln("" + snakeye + " snake eyes over " + rolls + " rolls of the dice.");
        TextIO.putln("" + snakeye / 1000.0 + " the average for  " + rolls + " rolls of the dice.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The average equals 0 though in what you wrote as both variables are int.

Comment: sorry about that .. I did not notice that .. i edited  it 
but Generally your loop is working well but the re write the if is wrong

Answer (score 0):

It's artificial but uses Java8

```
System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, 1000)               
                .mapToObj(x -> new Tuple((int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1, (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1))
                .filter(x -> x.a == 1 && x.b == 1)
                .count()); 

public static class Tuple
    {
        final int a;
        final int b;
        Tuple(int a, int b)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have to write my code with a for loop. So very close to what I wrote so far, except for this average that I am not able to figure out.